# Inserting text into a mysql database using a button

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working on a project and i am required to input text into the database based on a button click. The two options are Question and Demonstration. Both of these options are presented as buttons. What I would like to do is when I click, for example, question...a text "question" should be sent to my column in my database(called decision).

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

CheckSession.php

```
<?php

//Define your host here.
$HostName = "localhost";

//Define your database username here.
$HostUser = "root";

//Define your database password here.
$HostPass = "";

//Define your database name here.
$DatabaseName = "queue_lnsconnection";

?>
```

chooseOne.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'CheckSession.php';


$con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

  $Table_Name = $_REQUEST['test_android'];
   $Full_Name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $Decision = $_POST['decision'];


$CheckSQL = "SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'queue_lnsconnection'
AND table_name = '". $Table_Name . "'";



// $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL);
 //$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 //if(isset($check))

 if($result ==  true ){
    $Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO ".$Table_Name."(name,decision) values ('".$Full_Name."','".$Decision."')";

     if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
    {
        echo 'Request added to Queue';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Something went wrong';
    }
 }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

DecisionActivity.java

```
public class DecisionActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    // Creating button;
    Button Question;
    Button Demo;

    // Creating Volley RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue;


    // Creating Progress dialog.
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // Storing server url into String variable.
    String HttpUrl = "http://192.168.2.150:8080/chooseOne.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_decision);
        Question = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decQuestion);
        Demo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decDemo);
        // Creating Volley newRequestQueue .
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DecisionActivity.this);

        // Assigning Activity this to progress dialog.
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DecisionActivity.this);
        Question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                decisionChosen();
            }
        });
        Demo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                decisionChosen();
            }
        });

    }

    public void decisionChosen(){

        // Showing progress dialog at user registration time.
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait, We are Inserting Your Data on Server");
        progressDialog.show();

        // Creating string request with post method.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                        // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        // Showing Echo Response Message Coming From Server.
                        Toast.makeText(DecisionActivity.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                        // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                        Toast.makeText(DecisionActivity.this, volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {


        };

        // Creating RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DecisionActivity.this);

        // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Any code would also be appreciated. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And you wanna do this in "Android" or "PHP"?

Comment: create 2 editText and a button that will take the input and do some sort of network call to your phpmyadmin web service

Comment: @kerbholz I edited to add the code i have been working on,it holds more than asked but I would just like to know if i was to click a button if text can be sent a table in a database

Comment: @Coder123 Is there any way to send a text to the database, just by using 2 buttons? no editTexts involved

Comment: well, you can read it from external file\json or hard coded string..

Comment: @Coder123 Could you please give me an example of that? Im kind of new to programming and would appreciate the extra help.